# Error from server (Forbidden): the server does not allow access to the requested resource (post replicationcontrollers)

Tags: kubectl

When run some command,

```
error occur:
/home/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# ./kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:53:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (Forbidden): the server does not allow access to the requested resource
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Thanks a lot

Comment: /home/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# ./kubectl run helloworld --image=canal-cni:latest --port=8888
Error from server (Forbidden): the server does not allow access to the requested resource (post replicationcontrollers)

Comment: os information
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

Comment: Linux SZV1000240235 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
install refer doc:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/manual/

Answer (score 0):

kube-apiserver --service-cluster-ip-range=10.1.0.1/24 --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --secure-port=0 --insecure-port=35001 --allow-privileged=True --advertise-address=100.109.165.127 --bind-address=100.109.165.127 --insecure-bind-address=100.109.165.127 
./kubectl version  -s 100.109.165.127:35001
in .profile
add all the ip in  no_proxy
suck as
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost,100.109.196.103,100.109.165.127"
the issue reolved